# What is the name of this?

Tags: new-home

Here is the picture of an item I do not know the name of. Please advise what is the correct name of it
[image: Home]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about housewares, not home improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valet stand. Or garment rack.
[picture, no endorsement implied](https://www.allmodern.com/ZACK--Atacio-Valet-Stand-50671-L66-K~ZAC1046.html?refid=GX87922699516-ZAC1046&device=c&ptid=169141576083&targetid=pla-169141576083&network=s&ireid=608569&gclid=CjwKCAjwza_mBRBTEiwASDWVvoS3QfNbjYgkO0zC-fzKaVe-onCWsE93aZ9Gq7aBY3KsnE-8g8IlmxoCZhgQAvD_BwE)